# Getting data through salesforce api using curl fails

Tags: curl, groovy, salesforce

I've been at this issue for some time now, and i think its time to look for help.

I am trying to get some basic information from the salesforce Rest api, using Groovy and simple "curls".

In order to get data from the salesforce api, i am getting the access token using:

```
def accessTokenCurl = 'curl -X post '+ salesforceUrl + '? 
grant_type=password&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username=' + userName + '&password=' + 
password + ' -H "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"'
```

which returns this:

```
{
access_token=00D1x0000008cHb!ARkAQE2kWaUtv_
f4ENopZ2ntgtu21ZPAieOWn7PR3bDO4No_
epsHUbOBo8ixq23qTIK4VqdhGdbJLaCmRNyoeVn2I8hJRf8L,
instance_url=https://test123.salesforce.com, 
id=https://test.salesforce.com/id/
00D1x0000008cHbeAI/0051x000000cQg1AAA,
token_type=Bearer, 
issued_at=1541489804275, 
signature=K4ij5MfP0iZD8J4xDeIWozuDEvnWovAc4d9yfVFpfGc=
}
```

which looks correct.

Now i want to access some simple data:

```
def testcurl = "curl 
https://test123.salesforce.com/services/data/v4.0/query/? 
q=SELECT+contact.AccountId+from+contact+where+contact.Email 
+=+mn@aety.io -H Authorization: OAuth " + accessToken
```

it returns with an error:

```
[{"message":"Session expired or 
invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

I've read multiple sites that it could be because the ! in the access token, so i replaced it using

accessToken.replace("!", '\!')

and it seems to do it correct, here is the "escaped" string:

00D1x0000008cHb!ARkAQEIE20ES9DRFoOXHiiIzFwOeGtnGBg15TYeEFz4t9TUYkSHY.guZ0bBbgRgGKXpbWZzlWrX3cDFT_LXmgBw2iGjRJA5W

as you can see, it has inserted an \ infront of "!".. so why the hell does it come with an Invalid session Id?!

Comment: are you using the instance url that you got back from the auth response where you got the access token?

Comment: Hi Gareth, thanks for your answer. I was not aware of that - but i can see the instance URL i get back from the Auth token call is exactly the same as what i was using :/.